# stable sort in linux

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, sed, awk

I have a file

```
ksh$ cat test
b d
b c
a b
a a
```

I want to sort on first field but I want stable sort i.e. order of 2nd field should remain the same. I want output as:

```
a b
a a
b d
b c
```

If I try:

```
ksh$sort -k1 -s test
```

I get

```
a a
a b
b c
b d
```

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You forgot to constrain the key fields. By default it uses until the end of the line.

```
sort -k1,1 -s t.txt
```

Comment: I think it might be worth explaining the `-s` for people who are having the same problem, but, unlike the original questioner, don't know about it. The `-s` is the same as `--stable` and without it, the order of the other columns won't be preserved.

Comment: I don't understand why, if I specify -k1,1 which says to sort on field 1 and only field one, I would need to ALSO specify -s to get it not to look at field 2! What was the point in specifying an end field if the thing is going to use the rest of the fields anyway? 
But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You must specify the end field:

```
sort -k1,1 -s test
```